# Expo Bare Workflow - How To Use And Setup react-native-pdf and react-native-blob-util - React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

What is the proper way to use native module in react native expo bare workflow ?
I want to use **react-native-pdf** and **react-native-blob-util**

But I got error :

**TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'ReactNativeBlobUtil.DocumentDir')**

And

**Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:**

- **Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.**

I have following this link : https://openbase.com/js/react-native-pdf

I read in the expo documentation we can use native module using expo bare workflow. And now my project is bare workflow. In the middle of building my apps using expo bare workflow I got and error when using **react-native-pdf** and **react-native-blob-util**

***I want when user click the button the apps will open the pdf file which have source link pdf from my server.***

Is it possible to setup using this native module in expo bare workflow since bare workflow in the documentation said it like this :

https://docs.expo.dev/introduction/managed-vs-bare/

**Bare Workflow**

> In the bare workflow the developer has complete control, along with
> the complexity that comes with that. You can use all packages from the
> Expo SDK, development builds, and all Expo and EAS Services.
> Configuration with app.json / app.config.js is mostly not supported in
> this context; instead, you will need to configure each native project
> directly.

Please give me a solution of this problem ? If it is not possible please point me to use another best pdf viewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finally solved the problem.**

**Native Module** cannot run in **Expo Go**

So **expo publish** will not working because it is run in **Expo Go**.

Instead, we must change to run in **native**. Use case example : **npm run android** or **expo run:android**. It will run into **bare workflow** with **native module** in our code.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. The fix for me was to rebuild the development client first.

```
npx expo start --dev-client -c
```

Then run android/iOS.

There is no need to build with `expo run:android`.